# Duplicate blank email nodemailer

Tags: express, nodemailer

I'm sending emails using my express app using Nodemailer. When sending the email I get two emails sent, one with everything correct and the other as a blank mail with the to field not filled out. Any tips on how to fix?
From the console log, it shows that it is only called once...

````
  console.log('called')
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MAIL,
      pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD,
    },
  })

  let message = ''
  switch (format) {
    case 'resetPassword':
      message = `There was recently a request to change the password for your account. If you requested this password change, click the link below to reset your password:
  <br><br><a href="${passwordKey}">${passwordKey}</a><br><br>

  If you did not make this request, you can ignore this message and your password will remain the same.`
      break

    default:
      break
  }
  let mail = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: `<${process.env.MAIL}>`,
    to: email,
    bcc: process.env.MAIL,
    subject: subject,
    html: message,
  })
  transporter.sendMail(mail).then((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  })
}```
````

Comment: you are calling `transporter.sendMail` twice, so just delete the second one?

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid now...